# Count the number of instances of values across multiple dimensions in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I'm currently looking to count the number of instances a values shared across multiple dimensions. For example, say I have the following set of data:

[image]

And I want to return something like:

[image]

But ideally in the form of a bar graph. I want to keep the names associated with the data, so I can filter lets say by all "Bobs" or all "Hannahs".

Does anyone have any advice on how to do this in Tableau?

Answer (score 4):

Here are a couple of ways you may be able to do this.

**1)** Create a calculated field for each food type. This is a bit cumbersome and you would need to add new ones for any new foods added. You calculations would look like this:

Hamburgers:
`SUM(IF [Food1] = 'Hamburgers' OR [Food2] = 'Hamburgers' THEN 1 END)`

Then you would make use of the `Measure Names` and `Measure Values` built-in fields.

[image]

---

**2)** You can normalize your data. If you are referencing a Excel or Text file, you can do this right in Tableau. Simply go to the Data Source tab, select the Food fields, and choose to Pivot them:

[image]

Goes to:

[image]

Now you can do:

[image]

---

Finally, both results support creating a bar chart:

[image]